# java certificate verification false on a different method but true on same method in same class

Tags: java

need help 
i am testing digital signature so i pass data and signed field is returned. 
when i  verify digital signature from same method it is true  but false in different method in same class

method 1 :

```
public byte[] DigitalSignfield(String data) throws Exception, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    DigitalSignature ac = new DigitalSignature();
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    signature.initSign(ac.getPrivate("KeyPair/privateKey"));
    signature.update(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
    byte[] signatureValue = signature.sign();

    signature.initVerify(ac.getPublic("KeyPair/publicKey"));
    signature.update(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
    System.out.println("verified start start ");
    System.out.println(signature.verify(signatureValue));
    System.out.println("verified end end ");

    return signatureValue;

}
```

this returns true

when signatureValue above is returned and passed to below method in the same class it is returning false

```
public Boolean VerifyDigital(byte[] data) throws Exception, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    DigitalSignature ac = new DigitalSignature();
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    signature.initVerify(ac.getPublic("KeyPair/publicKey"));
    signature.update(data);
    Boolean ok = signature.verify(data);
    return ok;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second method you're calling `update` with the signature-data and not the data that was signed (which was named `data` in the other method). You need to pass the original data to the second method as well, e.g. like this:

```
public Boolean VerifyDigital(String data, byte[] sigData) throws Exception, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    DigitalSignature ac = new DigitalSignature();
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    signature.initVerify(ac.getPublic("KeyPair/publicKey"));
    signature.update(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Boolean ok = signature.verify(sigData);
    return ok;
}
```

BTW: You shouln't pass the data to be signed as `String` but already as `byte[]` to make the methods more general and allow the signing of binary data as well.